# Log in to ssh slow for one user, but not another

Tags: server, bash, ssh, login, openssh

I'm running a server at home with Ubuntu 14.04. I have two users on the machine, say `user1` and `user2`, each able to ssh into the box. While `user1` logs in very quickly, `user2` takes about 20 seconds to log in. Logging in as `user2` with `ssh -v` shows that the main pause happens after this message:

```
debug1: Sending environment.
```

The `.bashrc` files for the two users are identical. (A `diff` on them produces no output.)
On the server, there is a line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with `AllowUsers user1 user2`. That same file has `UseDNS no` in it already.

This issue started only about a week ago; I've had no such issues for the previous couple of years that I've been running the machine.

Where should I look to find the root cause of the delay for the log in for `user2`?

UPDATE: On a whim, I created a new user, `user3`, gave that user ssh access by editing `sshd_config`, and log in for the new user is fast. So it really seems to be something about the way `user2` is configured. But what?

Comment: One of them root?

Comment: Neither is root, but both are in the `sudo` group.

Comment: That does not matter. However, `root` has less checks in system call codepaths, therefore, non-`root` user may be slower.